# "Download Blob" using Interactive Grid

Tags: blob, oracle-apex

What is equivalent to the Interactive Report "Download Blob" for Interactive Grids?

Currently I am using an Interactive Report as my workaround but would like to use Interactive Grid however there is no Download Blob column type and I don't want to hack a URL in the select clause.

Comment: Are you using APEX 5.1 or 18.1?

Comment: Addind a url is not hacking. It's considered pretty normal in Apex

Answer (score 4):

Here are some steps that show you how it's done in APEX 19.2. Feel free to adjust as needed for other versions of APEX and as per your business requirements.

1. Create a table to store BLOB files and add a file as an example.

   ```
   create table files (
       id            number generated by default as identity,
       mime_type     varchar2(255),
       name          varchar2(255),
       content       blob,
       constraint files_pk primary key (id)
   )
   /

   insert into files (
     mime_type,
     name,
     content
   ) values (
     'text/plain',
     'test.txt',
     hextoraw('48656c6c6f20576f726c6421')
   );

   commit;
   ```
2. Create a new Interactive Grid page on the table using this query:

   ```
   select id,
     mime_type,
     name,
     dbms_lob.getlength(content) file_size
   from files
   ```
3. Create a new Blank Page in your application. Set **Page Number** to 9000 and set **Name** to Download File.
4. In the left-hand column of the Page Designer, right-click **Content Body** (under **Regions**) and select **Create Region**. Right-click the new region and select **Create Page Item**. Set the **Name** of the new item to P9000_FILE_ID and set the **Type** to Hidden. Note that neither the region or its item will ever be displayed.
5. In the left-hand column of the Page Designer, open the **Pre-Rendering** section, right-click **Before Header**, then select **Create Process**. Set the **Name** of the process to Download File and enter the following code for the **PL/SQL Code**:

   ```
   declare

     l_files_rec files%rowtype;

   begin

     select *
     into l_files_rec
     from files
     where id = :P9000_FILE_ID;

     owa_util.mime_header(l_files_rec.mime_type, false);
     htp.p('Content-Length: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(l_files_rec.content));
     htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || l_files_rec.name || '"');
     owa_util.http_header_close;

     wpg_docload.download_file(l_files_rec.content);

     apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

   end;
   ```

   This PL/SQL code is what gets the file from the database and streams it to the browser. You may want to modify this code, for example, to ensure a user should have access to the file they are trying to download. Also, consider application and page level security.
6. In the Page Designer, return to the Interactive Grid page. Right-click **Columns** under the Interactive Grid region and select **Create Column**. Set **Column Name** to Download, **Type** to Link, and (under **Source**) set **Type** to None. Click the **No Link Defined** button for **Target** to open the link settings. Set **Page** to 9000, use the popup to select P9000_FILE_ID under the **Name** column, use the popup to select ID under the **Value** column (in the same row), then click the OK button. Finally, set **Link Text** (under **Target**) to download.

To test, run the page and click the download link. The browser should download the file and when you open it the contents should be: Hello World!