# Show header when no data in interactive report oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have APEX interactive report on a table. I see the column headers when there is data in that table but I just get " no data found" message when there is no data in the table. Is it possible to still show column headers in that case ?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not supported by the Interactive Report. However, it is supported by the Interactive Grid. Depending on how important this functionality it to you, you could consider a read-only Interactive Grid.

Comment: Thanks, i don't think that. because some columns ( blob type) , and the interactive grid doesn't support the download

Comment: I just answered this other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814657/download-blob-using-interactive-grid/59774904#59774904

Comment: No problem, let me know how it turns out!