# Download BLOB image from custom table

Tags: oracle-apex

I have list view with advanced formatting which one displays uploaded images. After each image I want to add download link (for example: `<a href="&IMAGE_URL.">Download &IMAGE_NAME.</a>`). How I can to do that? I understand that I have to prepare URL and probably write PL/SQL, but I can't find solution.
SQL Query:

```
select  ID,
        PHOTO,
        MIMETYPE,
        FILENAME,
        LAST_UPDATE,
        ADDED_BY
from PHOTO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution ([link to topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814657/download-blob-using-interactive-grid)). In SQL Query I inserted `APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL('f?p=&APP_ID.:2:&APP_SESSION.:::2:P2_IMAGE_ID:' || ID) LINK`. In attributes I added `<a href="&LINK.">Download &FILENAME.</a>`. After that I created a new page with PL/SQL Code from answer ([link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59774904/11461370)). And after that it works like I need.

Comment: If you have APEX REST services enabled, you can use those also to serve your content instead of doing it using a page.